# How to change Mollie styles in Shopware 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopware, shopware6

I was wondering how can i change the default styles of Mollie Plugin in Shopware 6?

what i tried so far:

1. using css to change credit-card components styles
2. using jQuery and Javascript to overwriting CSS in JS files
3. tried to change Plugin JS files directly but I need to `build:storefront` (and with next update it all will lost)

all things that I already tried didn't work.
please if you have any idea i really appreciated.

I need to change this red color:
[image: Credit card box]

Comment: did 3. work (despite the fact that it will be lost after the update)? Which style do you wan't to change exactly? Can you illustrate with a screenshot? Did you check if the part of the payment form you are trying to modify is in an iframe? Because Iframe styles normally cannot be modified.

Comment: Hi @Alex , thanks for reply. it's not in a Iframe it uses a javascript in Mollie Plugin inside Shopware 6, to add a red color. and the problem is that i can't change that JS file or overwrite it.

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: @Alex I need to change the red color to black. i tried it with css ( not working )

Comment: Yes it needs to be passed to the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is in an iframe, you cannot change it directly.

But if you look at the src of the iframe, the Moolie server accepts parameters for the background color. This can theoretically be changed from Shopware 6 side by adapting the module. (see https://docs.mollie.com/components/styling)

Anyways, the Mollie module does not seem to use the standard error color from the Theme. I would consider this a shortcoming / bug in the module and recommend you try to report it to the module vendor.

[image: Iframe]

Comment: thanks for your answer Alex. I have already report this to Mollie Support but i didn't get an Answer yet...